# Wi-Fi suddenly not working on 23.10

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've installed the 23.10 iso on my work machine before it got taken down, and everything was working flawlessly. However, after booting up this morning I can't connect to wifi anymore. Tried a few things to get it back to work but nothing has solved the problem so far.

I'm running a Thinkpad L-13 with an Intel Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi wifi chip.

In systemd's logs, it says:

```
NetworkManager: rfkill4: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch
```

everytime I try to connect with the GUI.

With nmtui, when trying to activate a connection, I get:

```
Could not activate connection: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

The wifi works on the Ubuntu 23.10 live usb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Noticed an error message at boot that mentioned a netplan error. I ran

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

and then deleted a problematic yaml config file that was probably generated when I changed DNS. Everything is now back to normal.

Comment: Worked for me as well, thank you!

The YAML fiel in question for me was /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml. Just in case, I moved it to /tmp instead of immediately deleting:

sudo mv /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml /tmp/

Answer (score 2):

Just an improvement to the answer by Andre above.

When I ran the command,

> sudo netplan --debug generate

I got to know the problematic Wi-Fi connection and the .yaml file with the following error message `error in network definition duplicate access point ssid`

Move the problematic .yaml file to somewhere else (May be /tmp).
(Instead delete the problematic .yaml file, better we can move it or having a copy to avoid the loss of file)

> sudo mv /etc/netplan/90-NM-afxxxxxc2-2xxc-4xx4-9xxx-exxxxxxxxx8.yaml /tmp/

(The name of the problematic .yaml is different for person to person)

Once it moved you can make sure all good by run the `sudo netplan --debug generate` command, where no error message will be appear.

Then you can be able to connect to the Wi-Fi by clicking it!
(A system restart/reboot might be also good before connecting to Wi-Fi again)

Comment: I have more than 30 files in/etc/netplan... How do I know which file to move?

Comment: Please run 'sudo netplan --debug generate' command. There will be an error message where you could find the problematic .yaml file. If there is no error message displayed, then it is entirely a different problem.

Comment: Thanks, @Danny, I shall do that.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me also,I moved the /etc/netplan/filename.yaml(different for everyone) to /tmp.
Find your file with `$ sudo net plan--debug generate` then move it,the wifi should now work.